# React native check if tablet or screen in inches

Tags: android, ios, react-native, tablet, screen-resolution

I've established a different render logic for tablets and mobile devices. I was wondering if there is a way to **get the screen size in inches** or maybe even any module to automatically **detect if the device is a tablet or not**.

The reason I am not using the dimensions api directly to get the screen resolution is that there are many android tablets with lower resolution than many of their mobile counterparts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on @martinarroyo's answer, a way to go about it use the [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) package.

However the android implementation is based on screen resolution. That can be a problem as there are many tablet devices with a lower resolution than many mobile devices and this can cause problems.

The solution I will be using and am suggesting is use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) for apple devices and for android devices go with a simple ratio logic of the type:

```
function isTabletBasedOnRatio(ratio){

if(ratio > 1.6){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}

}
```

This is not a perfect solution but there are many small tablets with phonelike ratios as well or even phablets ( android is blurry) and this solutions is inclusive towards those as well.

Comment: can you elaborate how this ratio type works and how many devices comes under this roof.

Comment: Can you explain why 1.6?

Comment: at the time it was a reasonable ratio but right now im still unsure as to handle this. was just a heuristic solution

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) package along with the Dimensions API. Check the `isTablet()` method and apply different styles according on the result.

Comment: Hey martin, i just looked into the package and i realised that even though it works well for apple devices, the logic for the android is based on screen resolution as well. I will use your answer and merge it with an answer of my own if you dont mind.

Comment: Sure thing, it would also be helpful if you could post your final solution :)

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use library [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) use can use this code below, not sure it't work perfect but may be help

```
export const isTablet = () => {
  let pixelDensity = PixelRatio.get();
  const adjustedWidth = screenWidth * pixelDensity;
  const adjustedHeight = screenHeight * pixelDensity;
  if (pixelDensity < 2 && (adjustedWidth >= 1000 || adjustedHeight >= 1000)) {
    return true;
  } else
    return (
      pixelDensity === 2 && (adjustedWidth >= 1920 || adjustedHeight >= 1920)
    );
};
```

Comment: Similar solution is suggested [here by Adrian Hall](https://adrianhall.github.io/react%20native/2017/07/26/handling-orientation-changes-in-react-native/)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
npm install --save react-native-device-info
```

then

```
import Device from 'react-native-device-info';

const isTablet = Device.isTablet();
```

Comment: The most recent version of react-native-device-info reports foldable devices like the Galaxy Fold to report`Device.isTablet();` as true, even when they're folded and in "phone mode". I'm going to be switching to aspect-ratio detection instead of the `react-native-device-info` result so I can support those types of phones in both open and closed mode.

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-device-detection](https://github.com/m0ngr31/react-native-device-detection)

```
if(Device.isTablet) {
  Object.assign(styles, {
    ...
  });
}
```

Based on PixelRatio and Screen's height,width.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below example you can find the device is ios, android, tablet or small device

```
import { Platform, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const aspectRatio = height / width;

const isIOS = Platform.OS === 'ios';
const isAndroid = Platform.OS === 'android';

const isTablet = aspectRatio < 1.6; // Assumes 4:3 aspect ratio for tablets
const isSmallDevice = width < 375; // Assumes iPhone 6/7/8 width as small device

// Example usage in a component
const MyComponent = () => {
  const deviceType = isTablet ? 'tablet' : 'phone';
  const platformType = isIOS ? 'iOS' : 'Android';

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Device Type: {deviceType}</Text>
      <Text>Platform Type: {platformType}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```