# Add condition when device is tablet

Tags: react-native, tablet

I want to detect what device is used, to do so I would like to use Expo-device.
I want to set up the screens so that when the device used is a tablet, the left side of the screen is one component and the right side another component (i'd like to split the screen 66,66% left and 33.33% right).

How can I set up a condition to say that if the device is a tablet I want the screen on landscape mode and add a component on the left side of the screen?

For example let's say that, when I use an iphone or android phone I have this (that would be the right component on tablet):

```
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("../../assets/images/background.jpg")}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
      >
        <Header
          backgroundImage={require("../../assets/images/bg-header.png")}
          centerComponent={{
            text: i18n.t("about.title"),
            style: styles.headerComponentStyle
          }}
          placement="center"
          containerStyle={styles.headerContainerStyle}
          statusBarProps={{ barStyle: "light-content" }}
        />
        <ScrollView style={styles.containerScroll}>
          <Text style={styles.h3}>{i18n.t("terms.title")}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.h5terms}>{i18n.t("terms.content")}</Text>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.touchable2}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings")}
            >
              <View style={styles.view2}>
                <Text style={styles.textimg2}>
                  {i18n.t("signup.action.back")}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Image
                source={require("../../assets/images/btn-background.png")}
                style={styles.tripsimg2}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <Text>{"\n\n"}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check this link, it will help to resovle [React native check if tablet or screen in inches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44564327/932011)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I'm gonna take a look at this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info
This plugin gives you DeviceInfo. DeviceInfo has "isTablet()" method.

using expo-device:

```
import * as Device from 'expo-device';

Device.getDeviceTypeAsync()
```

Example Usage:

https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/416771c5c1ca562d0f87a98c3bdea292a736ebe4/apps/native-component-list/src/screens/DeviceScreen.tsx

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I've seen this package but I thought Expo-device could do the same job ?

Comment: Yes, it can. If you observe expo device library "getDeviceTypeAsync"
Following is example: 
https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/416771c5c1ca562d0f87a98c3bdea292a736ebe4/apps/native-component-list/src/screens/DeviceScreen.tsx

Answer (score 1):

yaa u can use Device info library ...
after that u have to get width and hieght = this will get by using Device info
then u can easily make condition

Here i am providing u the link of library =
=>  https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info

And one more thing u can do
after the installation u can use method isTablet()

it will provide u boolean value
after the value u can do anythin u want